# SQLAlchemy: Deleting multiple records at a time using in_ operator

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table that has thousands of rows. I want to delete multiple rows using in clause.

SQL Serrver code:

```
DELETE tbl_Jenny_ACW_AG2_AGENT_DAY_Genesys_Stage
WHERE Avaya_Id IN ('','',''....'')
```

I am trying to perform the above operation by using SQLAlchemy,

```
qry = (session.query(
                tbl_Jenny_ACW_AG2_AGENT_DAY_Genesys_Stage.c.Avaya_Id,
                func.count(),
                )
        .group_by(
                tbl_Jenny_ACW_AG2_AGENT_DAY_Genesys_Stage.c.Avaya_Id,
                )
        # comment this line out to see all the groups
        .having(func.count()>1)
      )

dlt_dup = tbl_Jenny_ACW_AG2_AGENT_DAY_Genesys_Stage.delete().where(tbl_Jenny_ACW_AG2_AGENT_DAY_Genesys_Stage.c.Avaya_Id.in_(qry))

session.execute(dlt_dup)
```

The above code will query the result and executes the query. But, I am unable to delete the duplicate records the error which I am getting is [parameters: (1,)]

Answer (score 0):

```
qry = db.session.query(Tablename.ColumnName, func.count()).filter(condition=value).group_by(Tablename.ColumnName).all().

db.session.delete(qry)
```

Comment: Did this answer help you?